# Call apachesolr_mark_entity without node_save

Tags: nodes, search

I need your advise. I have this code:

```
$nid = 5; //example
$engine = 'mustang';
$node = new stdClass();
$node->nid = $nid;          // node id
$node->type = 'car';  // aka content type
$node->engine[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $engine;
field_attach_update('node', $node);
//send to solr
apachesolr_mark_entity('node', $nid);
```

The code was used to update a field called engine in content type car without using `node_save()`. This way is used because more lightweight then calling using `node_load()` and then `node_save()`.

But unfortunately I can not send the entity to solr using `apachesolr_mark_entity()`. `apachesolr_mark_entity()` needs `node_save()` to work.

How to allow `apachesolr_mark_entity()` works although I don't use `node_save()`?

Answer (score 0):

> `apachesolr_mark_entity()` needs `node_save()` to work.

I would have to disagree; this is the code:

```
function apachesolr_mark_entity($entity_type, $entity_id) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'apachesolr', 'apachesolr.index');
  $table = apachesolr_get_indexer_table($entity_type);
  if (!empty($table)) {
    db_update($table)
      ->condition('entity_id', $entity_id)
      ->fields(array('changed' => REQUEST_TIME))
      ->execute();
  }
}
```

As you can see it's just a simple database update, `node_save()` is not involved.

Comment: yes I've also checked the function, but it's not been triggered with `field_attach_update()`. I've also checked in table `apachesolr_index_entities_node` (the condition is empty) there's no new data inserted.

Comment: so, when the node is never been sent to table `apachesolr_index_entities_node`, or let's assume the table is empty, node_save() will create new record to the table. what could possible make `field_attach_update()` works as `node_save()`. do I miss something in object `$node` ?